# Combination of elements of different lists or tuples

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I would like to get all the possible combinations between the elements of different lists or arrays. Let's say I have `L1 = [A,B]` and `L2 = [C,D]`. If I somehow use `itertools.combination` for Python to look for the combination for two elements the result would be `{AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,BC}`. The issue here is that I just need `{AC,AD,BC,BD}` because they are elements from different lists. Is there a conditional or something that could help me get combinations of `n` elements from different lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> L1 = ['A', 'B']
>>> L2 = ['C', 'D']
>>> list(product(L1, L2))
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D')]
```